# Animate interstitial Ad in android

Tags: android, admob, transition

Interstitial ad pops up suddenly when we call `interstitial.show();`

Is there any way to animate this transition, using `overridePendingTransition` etc.

Is it possible to animate existing activities like "com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible, but a workaround might be to create an activity that only shows the interstitial and animate that activity with overridePendingTransition. Maybe you could put a spinner on that activity when animating it before showing the interstitial. 
Let me know if you find out more on this.

Comment: How do I do it? Create an activity which only shows the interstitial? interstitial comes in its own activity. For your reference, please check the interstitial which are displayed in temple run. So nice and smooth.

Comment: I'm sorry, I downloaded temple run but couldn't see the interstitials you were talking about. I know however what you are trying to achieve... I really don't know how that might be done. What I was saying was that maybe you could make a view/activity coming from the side with a spinner or similar as to let the user know some content is coming and then load the interstitial, but I don't know how to actually animate the interstitial as an activity with PendingTransitions.

Answer (score 1):

It is posible. Use this in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyAnimation.Window</item>
</style>

 <style name="MyAnimation" /> 

<!-- Animations for a non-full-screen window or activity. --> 
<style name="MyAnimation.Window" parent="@android:style/Animation.Dialog"> 
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/in_left</item>
</style>
```

In `in_left.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<!-- Google Mobile Ads activity. -->
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

Or use some other animation in `in_left.xml`.

Comment: This holds only for AdActivities, right? OP asked for InterstitialAds that usually take only small part of the screen, not for fullscreen ads.

Comment: Using `overridePendingTransition` just after calling `interstitial.show() ` is also working on my side

Comment: after calling interstitial.show() works perfectly fine, but need animation right to left after ad is closed which is not working any help greatly appreciated.